# Utiliser « web » ou « Web » dans les rapports écrits en français

Tags: vocabulaire, terminologie, noms-propres

Est-ce que j'utilise « Web » ou « web » dans un rapport écrit en français ?

Answer (score 1):

« **le Web**» ([reverso](https://dictionnaire.reverso.net/francais-definition/web)) est la forme à utiliser quand il s'agit du nom de la chose en isolation. Lorsque le terme est utilisé dans un composé il faut utiliser « **Web** » ou « **web** ». Les exemples suivants sont tirés du reverso.

- télévision sur le Web
- logiciel de navigation sur le Web       nm   navigateur
- recherche sur le Web  :    n f,   recherche de l'information par Internet

---

- serveur Web :   n m,   serveur World Wide Web
- serveur World Wide Web   :     n m,  serveur Web
- caméras Web    :  n f pl,   webcams
- portail Web    :    n m,   portail Internet
- site Web  :   n m,   Internet, page Web, page WWW, page d'accueil, page Web, site Internet
- distribution Web :       n f,   webdiffusion

---

- adresse web  :   n f,   adresse électronique, adresse email, adresse ip, adresse internet, URL
- document web  :       n m,  page web, page html, page internet, page www, document web
- page web   :     n f,   site Web, page html, page internet, page www, document web
- site web :      n m,   site internet, site WWW, site
- conférence web   :      n f,   conférence par ordinateur, conférence internet, conférence vocale, conférence en ligne

Answer (score 1):

« web » est un mot anglais qui, bien que fréquemment utilisé, n'est pas encore entré au dictionnaire, il est recommandé d'utiliser « toile ».

J'aurais tendance à écrire « web » avec une minuscule étant donné que ce n'est pas un nom propre.

Comment: C'est une réponse  idéale mais qu'est-ce que l'on fait de tout le vocabulaire associé dont les partisans ne tiennent aucun compte et qui ne sera vraisemblablement jamais remplacé ? Un serveur Toile ? Des caméras toiles ? Une adresse toile ?  On doit donc forcer dans le langage cette dichotomie lexicale alors que l'on est à même de s'en débarrasser  ? Il me semble qu'il faille choisir : ou bien « toile », ou bien « web », ou bien autre chose. De plus, cet éclectisme morphologique a quelque chose de vraiment irrationnel : on passe à l'anglais pour les formes composées.

Comment: @LPH: Cela passera un jour ou l'autre dans le dictionnaire, personnellement j'utilise toujours « web » et, une fois sur mille, « toile » et encore uniquement dans l'expression « sur la toile ».

Comment: Le Larousse l'a bel et bien intégré https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/Web/82747?q=Web#526779

Comment: @Greg: C'est noté, je pense que c'est un ajout récent. Le terme « web » est néanmoins absent du TLFi. Par ailleurs, est-ce que cette réponse mérite vraiment un vote négatif ?

Comment: Le TLFi n'est plus mis à jour depuis 1994, il n'est pas étonnant que le terme en soit absent.